# Rating stars show incorrectly

Tags: java, android

Trying to show rating stars in a flexible way - means, with `wrap_content` height, or at least dp, and preferably vertically centered - but they're displayed always on top and remaining space filled with vertical lines. See image.

[image]

The XML:

```
<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/product_rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="33dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_big"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_big"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: also set `layout_width` to `33dp` I suppose, and it will work properly

Comment: Could you send me your drawable for test? thanks

Comment: What layout is the rating bar in?

Comment: @NeilTownsend in RelativeLayout and LinearLayout (using it in 2 different places). Both have the same problem.

Comment: I get the lines already on the designer - not related with device.

Comment: Well, not quite. I set layout_height to wrap_content again, and it fixed it in the designer! but not in the device........

Comment: what size is `star_ratingbar_big`?

Comment: Or, put another way, does it happen if you use the default drawablaes rather than yours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below to your styles.xml and set style to your rating bar  as **android:style="@style/myrating"** and width and height set to wrap_content for rating bar.

```
<resources>   
<style name="myrating" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_ratingbar_big</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">30dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dp</item>
</style> </resources>
```

Comment: I actually was using the style at the beginning, but disabled it to test. Reenabled and did like you say but still get the same.

Comment: Well, I don't know what it was, I deleted all my modifications and made it again and it works now. It works like this.